# Best way to hardcode data in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model, News, that has a ForeignKey to another model, Category.
The categories are defined with id, name, slug and a few more parameters.
My categories will never change in the future, so I am wondering why have I to store them in the database.
Is there any way to hardcode them inside the code, like using the choices or any other technique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, `choices`: store pairs of ID+name as a tuple of tuples and in another structure any other parameters.

```
CATEGORIES = (
    (1, "Some category"),
    (2, "Another category"),
)

CATEGORIES_PARAMS = {
    1: {'slug': 'param_value'},
    2: {'slug': 'another_value'},
}


class News(models.Model):
    category = models.IntegerField("category", choices=CATEGORIES)
    ...
```

then you can use other params following way:

```
CATEGORIES_PARAMS[news_instance.category]['slug']
```

or create simple wrapper class:

```
class Category(object):
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return CATEGORIES_PARAMS[self.id][attr]


cat = Category(news_instance.category)
print(cat.slug)
```

Comment: `The categories are defined with id, name, slug and a few more parameters` So, this is not possible.

Comment: I thought it is obvious how to store other properties, sorry... updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to create a relationship between your News and Category model using a ForeignKey, then there has to be a model Category. Now you're saying your Category will never change but in-case if they need to be changed in future, you need to redesign your code. To use django's full set of ORM features, it's always better to store it in the database and stick with the design.